# Selenium Java cannot resolve Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I try to start with Selenium.
But I am not able to get the imports from the Selenium working.

I did research on this issue and watched many youtube tutorials, but no clue, why the libraries cannot be imported for WebDriver or FirefoxDriver.
All is set buildpath as libraries.

Any idea? Also tried it with different JDKs 1.8, 17, 20

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKO4V.png)

- different JDKs 1.8, 17, 20
- different Selenium Java versions (currently with newest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which tutorials you followed and I don't know if you are using a build tool such as [maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [gradle](https://gradle.org/) or similar. I suggest to use them in case you are project doesn't have a build tool setup.

Just adding the following dependencies:

- [Selenium](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java)
- [Web Driver Manager](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)
- [Junit](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api) (this one in case you want to run selenium as an automated test

You should be able to execute the [hello world from the official doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/)

You have more examples of [selenium scripts in their github repo](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/tree/trunk/examples/java)

Answer (score 0):

because the WebDriver interface is not properly imported.
Import the WebDriver interface by:
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

(Make sure that you have imported the WebDriver interface at the beginning of your Java code.)